# How to return null inside the function/method if a property in the class is not found?

Tags: php, oop, multidimensional-array, php-5.3, stdclass

I use `stdClass` to convert an array to an object,

```
function array_to_object($array)
{
    if(!is_array($array)) {
        return $array;
    }

    $object = new stdClass();
    foreach($array as $key => $value)
    {
        $key = (string) $key ;
        $object->$key = is_array($value) ? array_to_object($value) : $value;
    }

    return $object;
}

$type = array(
    "category"  => "admin",
    "person"    => "unique"
);

$type = array_to_object($type);

var_dump($type->category); // string(5) "admin"
```

and of course an error when I want to get the property which is not set in the array in the first place,

```
var_dump($type->image);
```

error message,

```
Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$image in C:\wamp\www\test\2012\php\array_to_object.php on line 52
NULL
```

I wonder if I can make the function to return `null` if **no property** is found?

```
 var_dump($type->image); //NULL
```

**EDIT:**

Decided to make that function above into a class, but still cannot get `__get()` working properly,

```
class objectify
{
    public function __get($name)
    {
        if (isset($this->$name) === true){
            return $this->$name;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public function array_to_object($array)
    {
        if(!is_array($array)) {
            return $array;
        }

        $object = self::__get($name);
        foreach($array as $key => $value)
        {
            $key = (string) $key ;
            $object->$key = is_array($value) ? self::array_to_object($value) : $value;
        }
        return $object;
    }
}


$object = new objectify();

$type = array(
    "category"  => "admin",
    "person"    => "unique"
);

$type = $object->array_to_object($type);
var_dump($type->category);
var_dump($type->image);
```

error message,

```
Notice: Undefined variable: name in C:\wamp\www\test\2012\php\array_to_object.php on line 85
string(5) "admin" 
Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$image in C:\wamp\www\test\2012\php\array_to_object.php on line 107
NULL
```

I think this line is where the error from but I don't know what to do with it...

```
$object = self::__get($name);
```

Comment: A possible alternative, since you're probably generating these notices in specific, narrow areas of code(like your views or templates), is to temporarily remove E_NOTICE from php's error reporting level. Or use the [stfu operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php) eg echo `@$type->category;`

Comment: Thanks Chris for this tip! :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bringing John's answer about __get() together:

```
<? //PHP 5.3+

class maybeBag {
    public function __get($name){
        if (isset($this->$name) === true){
            return $this->$name;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static function ensureIsObject($values){
        if (\is_array($values) !== true){
            return $values;
        }
        $o = new static(); //Late-bound make instance of own class
        foreach($values as $key => $value){
            $o->$key = static::ensureIsObject($value);
        }
        return $o;
    }
}

//Demo

$type = array(
    'category' => 'admin',
    'person'   => 'unique'
);
$type = maybeBag::ensureIsObject($type);

var_dump($type->category); //string(5) "admin"
var_dump($type->image); //NULL

?>
```

Comment: For 5.3, the above should work by removing the keyword 'static' and using the old array syntax instead (array() instead of [])

Comment: yea I tested it and it works. but now I want to put the function `array_to_object` into a class and I get stuck here now. can you please have a look in my edit? thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Use this magic method inside your class. Whenever an undefined property is requested, null is returned.

For PHP 7:

```
public function __get($prop){
    return $this->$prop ?? null;
}
```

For PHP 5:

```
public function __get($prop){
    return isset($this->$prop) ? $this->$prop: null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Untested, but I think using the magic method `__get()` might work here:

```
public function __get($parameter)
{
    return (isset($this->$parameter)) ? $this->$parameter : null;
}
```

Comment: thanks but how can I use __get() in a function only (not in a class)?

Comment: Unfortunately you can't. It only works in objects. If you add it to your object after the fact it *should* work.